# How to link MATLAB to Webots lib?

Tags: matlab, webots

I created a MATLAB script for controller through wizards and uncommented
`desktop; keyboard;`
to interact with the MATLAB interface. Works are done on Win10.

My code works, but I have to start the MATLAB program from Webots to grant MATLAB access to Webots library. I tried opening MATLAB alone and had no clue about linking the program to Webots lib and project.

Another drawback is that every time I modify the codes and reset the simulation in Webots, MATLAB is restarted, which is annoying since it takes quite a time.

Q: Is there any way to link MATLAB to Webots lib so that I can develop the controller in MATLAB alone without starting Webots?

Comment: One quick way to fix it is to add the lib into the path. I am open to any other suggestions~

Comment: Did you try to follow these [instructions](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/running-extern-robot-controllers?tab-language=matlab&tab-os=windows) to run your MATLAB controller as an extern controller? It should resolve your problem, isn't it?

Comment: @OlivierMichel Hi Olivier, I followed the instruction and built an extern controller, and everything went well, EXCEPT MATLAB was shut down every time I reset the simulation. Is there any way to keep MATLAB loaded whenever I reset the simulation or reload the world? FYI, I use Webots R2020b and MATLAB R2020a. Thank you.

Comment: Can you quit your MATLAB program with **Ctrl + C** before resetting the simulation in Webots? Does it prevent your MATLAB from shuting down?

Comment: @OlivierMichel I can terminate the program with Ctrl +C in MATLAB. But it was still forced to quit when I reset the simulation and tried to launch the controller from MATLAB command window.

Comment: I tried it with MATLAB R2019b and I can indeed reproduce the behavior you describe. However, I don't understand why MATLAB terminates if the simulation was reset or reloaded. So, instead of resetting, you may use the supervisor process that will [reset the simulation without resetting the controllers](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor#wb_supervisor_simulation_reset). This should work, but the supervisor reset action should be called programmatically (not from the GUI).

Comment: @OlivierMichel Cool feature! I will try it out later. Thank you~

Answer (score 2):

Maybe below solve your problem.

**Solution**

In the launcher.m file (..\Webots\lib\controller\matlab):

- Change each line containing 'lib/matlab' to 'lib/controller/matlab'
- Lines are 15, 23, 132

and

In allincludes.h (..\Webots\lib\controller\matlab):

- Change each include path so that it goes back a further directory

  - eg: #include "../../../include/controller/c/webots/accelerometer.h"

Comment: What you suggest is already implemented in Webots R2020b.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, but does Keran have matlab 2020b?

Comment: It's not about MATLAB R2020b, but Webots R2020b which can be used with any recent version of MATLAB.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am using Webots 2020b right now and I guess the easiest way for me is to add the path of webots lib manually except MATLAB can be configured to do so automatically upon every launch. BTW, the extern controller is indeed worth looking into.